# Javascript Text loop on click

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop

I want to code in javascript that writes ten times the sentence “I know a bit of JavaScript” after clicking on a text within an `<h1>` tag. The code should use a for loop or a while loop and if statements. Must use a function to write the sentence.

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Why does this seem like word-for-word homework instructions?

Comment: Literally just someone's homework...

Comment: you can try that yourself. It just takes the basics of JavaScript.If you don't try this simple exercise then how you are going to learn programming

Answer (score 0):

I will not give you any code since this sounds like homework, but how about breaking the question down and googling every step of it.

Lets break it down:

1. Write ten times a sentace. Your code should use a loop.
   Lets check what the JavaScript docs say about while loops :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while
2. Clicking on a text within an tag:
   Lets check what the JavaScript docs say about the click event:
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click
3. You muse use a function to write the sentance
   Lets check what the JavaScript docs say about functions
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

So take it piece by piece. It doesn't have to to all the right things at once. Just break it down.

1. Try to make a while loop do something 10 times. Just to console.log('stuff') out. Just so that you see something happening 10 times.
2. Try to make a onClick event console.log('I got clicked'), just to make sure you have your event
3. Try to make a function do something.

   When you have a function that does something, a loop that runs 10 times and an onClick event that fires then its just a matter of putting it all together.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by for loop:

```js
const demoEl = document.querySelector('.demo')

const repeatElement = (repeatWord, repeatNumber) =>{
    let total = ""
    let error = false
    let errorMessage = ""
    if(repeatWord != null && repeatNumber != null){
        error = false
        for(let i = 0; i < repeatNumber; i++){
            total += `${repeatWord}\n`;
        }
    }else{
        error = true
        errorMessage = "Please fill all perimeter."
        return errorMessage
    }
    return total
}

// Calling Function
demoEl.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
console.log(repeatElement("I know a bit of JavaScript", 10))
})
```

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Stack Over Flow</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1 class="demo">DEMO</h1>      
    </body>
</html>
```